# NLTK and the process of Naive Bayes Classification

Tags: python, classification, nltk, bayesian

This may be a stupid question but I'll give it a shot.

Does anyone know the inner working of what the naive bayes command is doing, other than the execution of the algorithm it self?

The reason I ask is that two days ago I began running the classifier over 1.5 million tweets.  Two days later it is still running but when it began the memory used given by the task manager was at around 3gb...last night it dropped to 4mb so I was wondering what caused this drop? Is the programme doing anything any more? Am I wasting my time waiting for it to finish?

Any ideas would be great

Comment: Although I'm not familiar with NLTK's particular implementation, a Naive Bayes classifier by itself is very compact, and should not use any significant amount of memory. Are you *sure* it's the classification process that's causing the problem (as opposed to loading 1.5 million tweets)?

Comment: That may be the issue then, the loading time was using a lot of memory and took that amount of time and now it has just moved onto the actual classification process? Would that seem more realistic in your opinion?

Comment: NLTK isn't really up to that kind of scale. It's intended as a teaching tool and values readable code over optimizations.

Comment: @larsmans yeah im beginning to understand that now. anything you'd recommend that would process this better?

Comment: @user3244770 I'd recommend my own Naive Bayes implementation, which is part of [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org). That's obviously not unbiased advice, but I'm sure it's orders of magnitude faster than the one in NLTK. (There's a scikit-learn wrapper in NLTK, also by yours truly.)

Comment: @larsmans thanks for the recommendation! I've downloaded the module and I am looking for away to incorporate it in the code that I have, although not entirely sure I can without rewriting http://pastebin.com/cwZRXP3h.